# How to use an object in Squish as a pure QT object

Tags: python, qt, squish

I am trying to write a Squish script in python to print all children of a custom QObject. For confidentiality  reasons I cannot share any details about the QObject type. The script prints lists all children that are there in static .ui file bt not the ones added dynamically. Any suggestions.

Additionally, is there a way I an use the object(returned by waitForObject) as a pure QObject. If I call a a QT API using this object I get following error
"Script Error AttributeError: Object does not have any properties"

Comment: How do you get the list of child objects? Via [object.children()](https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#object.children-function)? object.children() should be using QObject.children(). Given that, how are these children added, perhaps they are not actual children in the sense of the Qt widget API? And yes, calling Qt API on object references returned by waitForObject() works: waitForObject({"type": "MainWindow"}).setWindowTitle("x")

Comment: I first tried the API findChildren but I got the error "Script Error AttributeError: Object does not have any properties". Then I tried object.children() but it is not listing all children. I wrote a C++ code to check it those widgets are children or not .. used the API findChildren.. it works. GammaRay tool is also able to detect all child widgets. My Squish python script is not working as expected. I am new to Squish.

Comment: I recommend contacting the vendor to analyze the problem. If you provide a dummy AUT for reproduction to them resolution should go very quick..